# how do I create labels based on checkbox states?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, checkbox, label

I'm writing an applet to purchase music. Basically it has 16 songs, song1, song2, song3, song4, etc. as check boxes.
The user should be able to choose the songs he/she wants to purchase, and click on add to cart to display the cart. The cart should have labels according to the checks made in the previous screen.

Eg: if song1, 3 and 5 are checked, the cart should display three labels - song 1, 3 and 5.

So, how do I create labels based on the checks, without having to create 16 labels before hand, and making a total mess? Should I somehow use an array?

it's kinda complicated because i've already created the checkboxes in a card layout. I've written an applet (using plain old notepad), with radio buttons to select a genre. Selecting a radio button displays 4 songs (this is where i've used the cards).

```
   content_cat.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content_cat,                

                                BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
   content_cat.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
   category_label = new JLabel("Select the category");
   category_label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
   content_cat.add(category_label);
   content_cat.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
   pop = new JRadioButton("Pop");
   pop.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
   content_cat.add(pop);
   content_cat.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
   rock = new JRadioButton("Rock");
   rock.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
   content_cat.add(rock);
   content_cat.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
   jazz = new JRadioButton("Jazz");
   jazz.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
   content_cat.add(jazz);
   content_cat.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
   hiphop = new JRadioButton("Hip hop");
   hiphop.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
   content_cat.add(hiphop);
   content_cat.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));

   group = new ButtonGroup();
   group.add(pop);
   group.add(rock);
   group.add(jazz);
   group.add(hiphop);

   pop.addItemListener(this);
   rock.addItemListener(this);
   jazz.addItemListener(this);
   hiphop.addItemListener(this);


   //List Panel

   content_list = new Panel();
   gbc_content.gridx = 1;
   gbc_content.gridy = 0;
   gbc_content.weightx = 3;
   gbc_content.weighty = 1; 
   gbc_content.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
   content.add(content_list,gbc_content);

    content_list.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //List Title Panel

    list_title = new Panel();
    gbc_list.gridx = 0;
    gbc_list.gridy = 0;
    gbc_list.weightx = 1;
    gbc_list.weighty = 1; 
    gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    content_list.add(list_title,gbc_list);
    list_label = new JLabel("List of CD's Available");
    list_title.add(list_label);

    //List Cards Panel

    list_card = new Panel();
    list_card.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    gbc_list.gridx = 0;
    gbc_list.gridy = 1;
    gbc_list.weightx = 1;
    gbc_list.weighty = 4; 
    gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    content_list.add(list_card,gbc_list);

    //Pop card

    card_pop = new Panel();
    card_pop.setLayout(new BoxLayout(card_pop,                     

                                               BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    card_pop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    pop1 = new JCheckBox("21 - Adele");
    pop1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_pop.add(pop1);
    card_pop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    pop2 = new JCheckBox("D'elles - Celine Dion");
    pop2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_pop.add(pop2);
    card_pop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    pop3 = new JCheckBox("Invincible - Michael Jackson");
    pop3.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_pop.add(pop3);
    card_pop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    pop4 = new JCheckBox("Speak Now - Taylor Swift");
    pop4.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_pop.add(pop4);
    card_pop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));

     //Rock card

    card_rock = new Panel();
    card_rock.setLayout(new BoxLayout(card_rock,                   

                                               BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    card_rock.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    rock1 = new JCheckBox("Let It Be - Beatles");
    rock1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_rock.add(rock1);
    card_rock.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    rock2 = new JCheckBox("Viva la Vida - Coldplay");
    rock2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_rock.add(rock2);
    card_rock.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    rock3 = new JCheckBox("Meteora - Linkin Park");
    rock3.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_rock.add(rock3);
    card_rock.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    rock4 = new JCheckBox("Dark Horse - Nickelback");
    rock4.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_rock.add(rock4);

    //Jazz card

    card_jazz = new Panel();
    card_jazz.setLayout(new BoxLayout(card_jazz,                   

                                               BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    card_jazz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    jazz1 = new JCheckBox("Come Sing With Me - Frank Sinatra");
    jazz1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_jazz.add(jazz1);
    card_jazz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    jazz2 = new JCheckBox("Closer - Josh Groban");
    jazz2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_jazz.add(jazz2);
    card_jazz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    jazz3 = new JCheckBox("Little Broken Hearts - Norah Jones");
    jazz3.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_jazz.add(jazz3);
    card_jazz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    jazz4 = new JCheckBox("Genius and Friends - Ray Charles");
    jazz4.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_jazz.add(jazz4);
    card_jazz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));

    //Hiphop card

    card_hiphop = new Panel();
    card_hiphop.setLayout(new BoxLayout(card_hiphop,               

                                               BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    card_hiphop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    hiphop1 = new JCheckBox("Curtis - 50 Cent");
    hiphop1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_hiphop.add(hiphop1);
    card_hiphop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    hiphop2 = new JCheckBox("Freedom - Akon");
    hiphop2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_hiphop.add(hiphop2);
    card_hiphop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    hiphop3 = new JCheckBox("Relapse - Eminem");
    hiphop3.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_hiphop.add(hiphop3);
    card_hiphop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    hiphop4 = new JCheckBox("Takin' Over");
    hiphop4.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    card_hiphop.add(hiphop4);
    card_hiphop.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));

    pop1.addItemListener(this);
    pop2.addItemListener(this);
    pop3.addItemListener(this);
    pop4.addItemListener(this);

    rock1.addItemListener(this);
    rock2.addItemListener(this);
    rock3.addItemListener(this);
    rock4.addItemListener(this);

    jazz1.addItemListener(this);
    jazz2.addItemListener(this);
    jazz3.addItemListener(this);
    jazz4.addItemListener(this);

    hiphop1.addItemListener(this);
    hiphop2.addItemListener(this);
    hiphop3.addItemListener(this);
    hiphop4.addItemListener(this);

  list_card.add(card_pop,POP);
  list_card.add(card_rock,ROCK);
  list_card.add(card_jazz, JAZZ);
  list_card.add(card_hiphop, HIPHOP);
```

There's a button at the bottom to "add to cart". When it is clicked, it opens a new frame with the shopping cart, and that's where i want to display the songs selected.

Here's the event handling code

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
 CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(list_card.getLayout());
 if(e.getSource() == pop)
 cl.show(list_card, POP);
 if(e.getSource() == rock)
 cl.show(list_card,ROCK);
 if(e.getSource() == jazz)
 cl.show(list_card, JAZZ);
 if(e.getSource() == hiphop)
 cl.show(list_card, HIPHOP);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
 if(e.getSource() == atc) //add to cart button
  {
   cart = new JFrame("Cart");
   cart.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

So basically, open the applet using appletviewer or a web browser, select the songs needed under each genre, click on add to cart to display a frame with the shopping cart.

sorry for copy-pasting so much code...

Comment: What GUI environment are you using?  I imagine there would be a way to create 5 labels and set the text within these labels dynamically.  If you only need <5 songs, you could hide the other labels.  Is that what you are thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

Create the song:

```
ArrayList<String> songsSelection = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList();

//add all songs you want
songs.add( new Song(1, "Song 1")); 
songs.add( new Song(1, "Song 1")); 
songs.add( new Song(1, "Song 1"));
```

create an anction in order to recognize the selection, here you can remove or add songs to selection according to checkbox state

```
class SongAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JCheckBox temp = (JCheckBox)e.getSource();
        if (temp.isSelected())
            songsSelection.add(temp.getName());
        else
            songsSelection.remove(temp.getName());
        updateCart();
    }
}
```

create the checkboxes

```
for(Song s : songs){
    JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(s.getName());
    cb.addActionListener(new SongAction());
    frame.add( cb );
}
```

now you can update your cart after selection

```
public void updateCart(){
    panel.removeAll(); // clean the labels container
    for(String name : songsSelection ){
        panel.add(new JLable(name))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the real question here is whether or not you need to use labels? Wouldn't it be just as effective, and considerably easier, to use a JTextArea to display which songs are selected for purchase?

Comment: yeah, I guess it should be easier! thanks!
one more tiny favor... can you tell me how to code the item listener to append the text area only when a checkbox is checked?

Comment: It seems to me that you would just place the listener on the checkbox, and have that append to the textarea. The easiest way, though, would be to have a single listener that triggers whenever a box is checked or unchecked, and instead of appending, completely rewrites the content of the textarea. That way you wouldn't have to worry about any kind of sorting algorithm-- just a few simple booleans.

Comment: don't think I really get what you're saying... would that give a complete list of the checks made? i used this code if(pop1.isSelected() == true); {item_list.append("21 - Adele" + new_line);} if(pop2.isSelected() == true) {item_list.append("D'elles - Celine Dion" + new_line);} if(pop3.isSelected() == true) {item_list.append("Invincible - Michael Jackson" + new_line);} if(pop4.isSelected() == true) {item_list.append("Speak Now - Taylor Swift" + new_line);}

got it working with coaxing(having to click on add to cart about 3 times), and several runtime exceptions
http://i46.tinypic.com/5dv13l.png

Comment: not really satisfied with the outcome of my experiment... have to get rid of the exceptions and make it work instantly when the boxes are checked and add to cart is clicked

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not too sure what went wrong there, sorry. Hopefully someone else knows more than I do.